# typescript automatically serialized a class instance?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, typescript

I just implemented a serializer for a class as follow:

```
import {File} from './file'
import Serialization from './serializable'

class User implements Serialization<User> {
  username: string
  deserialize(input) {
    this.username = input.username

    return this
  }
```

}

Some details are omitted

However, I thought to do serialization and convert this object into Json, I need to implement a serializer which is reverse to what I wrote in this deserializer

But the puzzling thing is, when I do:

```
app.use('/abc', (req, res) => {
  getLoggedInUser(sessionToken)
    .then(
      user => {
        const tmp: User = s
        res.send(tmp)
      }
    ).catch(
      err => {
        console.log("err =" + JSON.stringify(err))
      }
  )
```

express actually returned the JSON version of this User object.

I'm quite surprised by this behavior. Does that mean I don't need a serializer since it's done by typescript automatically? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an object or an array it will stringify it as JSON. From the Express docs:

> When the parameter is an Array or Object, Express responds with the
>   JSON representation:
>
> ```
> res.send({ user: 'tobi' });
> res.send([1,2,3]);
> ```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

Comment: Thanks for the reply. even if it's an instance of a class it will have this behavior?

Comment: An instance of a class is just an object. It will ignore the functions and stringify the own properties.